# replace tab in an enclosed string in a tab delimited file linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk, gsub

I have a tab delimited txt file in which third column contains enclosed  string that might also has a tab. Because of this extra tab i am getting 5 columns when i try to read this tab delimited file. So i want to replace the tab with space.

Following is the sample file.

```
col1   col2   col3        col4  
1      abc    "pqr   xyz" asd  
2      asd    "lmn   pqr" aws  
3      abc    "asd"       lmn
```

I want the output like this

```
col1   col2   col3        col4  
1      abc    "pqr xyz"   asd  
2      asd    "lmn pqr"   aws  
3      abc    "asd"       lmn
```

Here is what i have tried

```
awk -F"\t" '{ gsub("\t","",$3); print $3 }' file.txt
```

after that i am getting following output

```
col3  
"pqr  
"lmn  
"asd"
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having GNU awk (gawk) you can use the following expression:

```
gawk '{gsub("\t"," ",$3)}1' OFS='\t' FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^\t]*' file
```

The key here is the `FPAT` variable. It defines how a field can look like instead of just specifying the field delimiter.

In our case a field can either be an sequence of non-double-quote chars enclosed in double quotes `"[^"]*"` or a sequence of zero or more non tab characters `[^\t]*`. (zero, to handle empty fields properly)

Since we are specifying the sequence of non quote characters first it has a precedence.

Comment: Thanks a lot hek2mgl.

Comment: ^1 and just for completeness - in other awks you'd use `awk 'match($0,/".*"/) { tgt=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/\t/," ",tgt); $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) } 1' file`

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl, The    gawk '{gsub("\t"," ",$3)}1' OFS='\t' FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^\t]+' file  works fine when all columns have some value. But if few columns doesn't have any value but tab itself then it doesn't produce desired output. Can you please help.

Comment: @arshad There was a little bug. I've edited my answer and changed `[^\t]+` to `[^\t]*` in `FPAT`. Try it again! It should work as expected now.

Comment: Thanks again @hek2mgl